# Monte Carlo integration error

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

I have a question regarding the Monte Carlo integration method. This is probably a "noob" question, but I have searched the internet and haven't been able to find an answer...

Let's say I want to estimate an integral of some function over an area $D$, that I'll denote as $I$. I can choose $N$ points to randomly sample from $D$ in order to obtain the integral, the error should "decay" as $err\sim \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$, so that $I\sim \overline{I}\pm\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$. But what if I just ran the simulation $N$ times and would get different values like: $I_1,I_2,....I_N$ those should be distributed normally as well, right? So I can estimate the error from those values again as $I\sim\overline{I} \pm \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$, would this give the same results or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the integrals from your $N$ simulations would be Normally distributed?   The rate of convergence of the Monte Carlo integral to the true value is not dependent upon any specific distributional assumption.  You also *appear* to be confusing a simulation with $N$ points and $N$ simulations, unless you mean your $N$ simulations are each of one point... which of course is, in the case of independent simulations and points, exactly the same as one simulation of $N$ points.

Comment: So... what you’ saying is that if I make N simulations of N points and each simulation represents one points, as $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} I_N =I $ and all points are the same... And actually those different values for the repeated simulations I get  for “different” $I_N$ are basically due to some random errors because $N$ is not infinite? But what would the distribution of those different values for $I$ be , why wouldn’t it be normal?

Comment: Your initial sentence makes no sense:  "if I make N simulations of N points and each simulation represents one points".   If your simulation is of N points, it represents N points.  What are you actually trying to say?  And I cannot understand your last sentence either.   Forget the Normal distribution, it has nothing to do with this problem!

Comment: I make a “simulation” of the  integral $\int_D f(\textbf x) d\textbf x=I$ using N sampling points that lie in $D$, and then I calculate N such integrals and I lable them as $I_1,I_2,...I_N$, all of those values from $I_1$ to $I_N$ will be, in general, different. Maybe they are normally distributed and I can use that to estimate the error....

Comment: “if I make N simulations of N points....” means what if I calculate N simulations of the same integral that I compute using N sampling points from $D$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As rightly stressed in the comments of [J Bowman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7555/jbowman), there is a fair amount of confusion in this question. Considering

1. $N$ simulations from a uniform distribution on the set $\mathfrak{D}$, $x_1,\ldots,x_N$, the estimator$$I_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N h(x_i)$$is an unbiased estimator of$$\mathfrak{I}=\int_\mathfrak{D} h(x)\text{d}x$$ that a.s. converges at the speed $\sqrt{N}$ in the sense of the Central Limit Theorem:$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^N \{h(x_i)-\mathfrak{I}\}\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
   which variance $\sigma^2$ can be estimated by the empirical variance of the $h(x_i)$'s. This means that $I_N$ is approximately Gaussian for large $N$'s, with variance $\sigma^2/N$
2. When considering an iid sequence $I_N^1,\ldots,I^N_N$ of such estimators, they all are unbiased estimators of $\mathfrak{I}$ with the same variance $\sigma^2/N$ that can be estimated by the empirical variance of the $I_N^i$'s, and again satisfy a CLT:
   $$\frac{\sqrt{N}}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^N \{I^i_N-\mathfrak{I}\}\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
   This means that $I_N^1,\ldots,I^N_N$ is approximately a Gaussian sample for large $N$'s, again with variance $\sigma^2/N$
3. Letting $N$ grow to infinity in $I_N^1,\ldots,I^N_N$ does not serve a clear purpose, as opposed to computing a single $I_{N^2}$ based on the same number of simulations, $N^2$, which has a variance of $\sigma^2/N$